# fill vector values between specified indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Starting from a vector `a` and a list `ind` of indices, I want to set the elements of `a` corresponding to indices in `ind` as a function of the original vector (in the example I will just add 10 to the original value), and want to keep the value calculated in correspondence to each index in `ind` for all following elements until the next index.

For example, given:

```
a = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
ind = [0, 2, 4]
```

return:

```
result = [20, 20, 22, 22, 24, 24]
```

You can notice that the elements of `a` not corresponding to indices in `ind` are completely irrelevant. Also, there is an indetermination on first element if its index is not in `ind`, so I want to be able to set a default value for first element that is used if `0` is not in `ind`, then the complete set of test cases is:

```
#test
a = np.array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])

fill(a, [2, 4], -50)
#[-50, -50, 22, 22, 24, 24]
fill(a, [0, 2, 4], -50)
#[20, 20, 22, 22, 24, 24]
fill(a, [0, 2, 4, 5], -50)
#[20, 20, 22, 22, 24, 25]
```

I can easily do it with a loop, but this is going to be slow if vector `a` is large:

```
def fill(a, ind, startval):
    res = np.zeros(len(a) + 1)
    res[0] = startval
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if i in ind:
            res[i + 1] = a[i] + 10
        else:
            res[i + 1] = res[i]
    print(res[1:])
```

what is the most effective way of doing it?

Comment: thanks for the edits.

Comment: 2+ years later: you're welcome. I finally figured out how to fix my answer and undeleted it after all these years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method using `diff` on the indices to obtain block sizes and then `repeat` on the values to create the blocks.

```
def fill(a,ind,f=lambda x:x+10,default=-50):
    sizes = np.diff(ind,prepend=0,append=len(a))
    values = np.concatenate([[default],f(a[ind])])
    return values.repeat(sizes)
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me `prepend`. If seen the discussion about it before, but forgotten that it was added. My last project is jumping through hoops to get those extra framing elements right now.

Comment: I'll see if I can throw together a PR. We can just factor out the code `diff` uses into a utility function. It would be almost trivial.

Answer (score 2):

While `np.repeat` is clearly the way to do here, `np.cumsum` is also an option. The only thing you need to calculate is the difference between the successive elements. Given that `np.diff` is basically the inverse of `np.cumsum` and zero elements don't affect the cumsum, you can do something like this:

```
def fill_cumsum(a, ind, f=lambda x:x + 10, default=-50):
    vals = np.diff(f(a[ind]))
    a = np.zeros_like(a)
    a[0] = default      # Do this first
    a[ind[0]] = a[ind[0] - np.sign(ind[0]) * default
    a[ind[1:]] = vals   # Overwrite zero automatically
    return a.cumsum()
```

If you want to do the same thing in-place, just change `a = np.zeros_like(a)` to `a[:] = 0` and add `out=a` to the return `cumsum`.

The two answers are almost the same speed:

```
a = np.random.randint(1000, size=10000)
ind = np.unique(np.random.randint(10000, size=100))
%timeit_repeat fill(a, ind)
43 µs ± 659 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit fill_cumsum(a, ind)
35.6 µs ± 367 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

a = np.random.randint(1000, size=100000)
ind = np.unique(np.random.randint(100000, size=100))
%timeit fill(a, ind)
237 µs ± 592 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit fill_mp(a, ind)
245 µs ± 521 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

This answer works great for integers, but `np.repeat` introduces less floating point roundoff error since it does not call `np.diff`.

Answer (score 0):

I accepted Paul Panzer's answer, that is very smart and works magically.
However, for completeness, I want to add also my own answer.

This solution is more flexible because it allows values of resulting vector to be determined by previous elements, but I don't like it because of the nested `if`.

I failed in finding a choice of indices that can eliminate nested loops and IFs, but from a number of tests, the two solutions are equivalent in terms of execution time (with my initial example in question being about 1000 times slower):

```
def fill(a,ind,startval):
    res=np.zeros(len(a))
    for i,it in enumerate(ind):
        if i == 0:
            if it == 0:
                res[0]=a[0]+10
            else:
                res[0:it]=startval        
        else:
            res[ind[i-1]:it]=res[ind[i-1]]
        res[it]=a[it]+10
    res[ind[-1]:]=res[ind[-1]]
    print (res)
```